# Use same montior config on many docking stations

Tags: powershell

My company moved to a new office with about 400 'freefloating' desks. Every morning, I arrive, find a free spot, connect my laptop, and start working. Each desk has an identical set-up, with a big monitor and a docking station.

Now, every time I sit down at a desk I haven't sat at before, I need to configure the monitor set-up:

1. Extend the display
2. Make the external monitor the main one
3. Position the laptop screen to the left of the external one, with their bottom edges alligned.

It's not a *lot* of work, but do it every single day for a few weeks and you too will want to automate it.

**Is there a small script I could use to get these settings done?**

I found `DisplaySwitch.exe` but that only does the first step.

Comment: Too difficult for y'all? ;) :p